# Why is BoxCutter NGON cutter tool is not cutting where I ask it to?

Tags: bisect

The BoxCutter NGON cutter is not cutting correctly. Image one shows the cutter, which should just cut the corner of the mesh where the red triangle goes over it. The second image shows what the cutter is actually doing. I have also attached my settings panels.

I have tried changing the cutter settings between 'world' and 'view' etc, to no avale. I've tried the other cutters and they're working fine, which makes me think it's a mistake I've made in the settings rather than a software issue.

I have tried getting in touch with the add on developer on Gumroad (Master Xeon) but there is no contact form.

If anyone can see what I've enabled that is causing this please let me know.

[image: The red triangle is the cutter. It should just remove the corner where it's over lapping the mesh but...]

[image: ...this is the cut it made]

[image: These are the addon settings I have. I'll show the top bar as well in case it's useful]

[image: Top bar settings]

Comment: Sorry but we can only help with Blender's built-in addons not with commercial third-party ones.

Comment: There is a contact link below the purchase section on the [Blender Market](https://blendermarket.com/products/boxcutter) entry for the addon. You will have to register with Blender Market first though.

Comment: Seems to me that the cutter is projecting in orthographic while you see in perspective. You might try setting your viewpoint to orthographic to work around the problem.

Comment: @TheLabCat thank you, this was exactly the problem as answered by the creator of the add on once I finally manged to contact them.